# How to exclude values in the data load editor

Tags: qliksense

I am just starting to learn QlikSense and I was wondering how I exclude values in the data load editor.

Specifically, I want to exclude Product X, Product Y, and Product Z from the Orders column.

I have tried placing `where` statements around, but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can think of few way to achieve this:

**Option 1**

Just list the orders that are not needed

```
Where
      Orders <> 1
  and Orders <> 2
  and Orders <> 3
```

**Option 2**

Using [match](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/September2017/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Scripting/ConditionalFunctions/match.htm) function

```
Where
  Match(Orders, 1, 2, 3) = 0
```

**Option 3**

Using [exists](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/September2017/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Scripting/InterRecordFunctions/Exists.htm) function to filter the records based on records from another table

```
OrdersToExclude:
Load
  *
Inline [
  Orders
  1
  2
  3
];

FiteredData:
Load
  *
Resident
  RawData
Where
  Not Exists( ToExclude, Orders )
;

Drop Table OrdersToExclude;
```

Table `Join` can be used as well